# Revert snapshot before or after each test method in a TFS build-deploy-test workflow?

Tags: tfs, build-automation, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I have a scenario that requires me to revert to a clean snapshot before or after each Coded UI test method is executed.  I have researched using the TFS Lab Management API (see http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2011/12/22/tfs-api-part-42-getting-started-with-lab-management-api/) to revert to a specific snapshot as part of the TestInitialize and/or TestCleanup method, but I can only get this to work when executed locally.  When executed on a remote machine I get errors authenticating to the TFS service.

My other option is to somehow do a 'foreach test in testrun' into the build process template (LabDefaultTemplate.11.xaml).  I have identified the area that I think this would fit best, but cannot find any documentation on running a loop on each test.

Is this something that is possible, or is there somehow a built in method to accomplish this that I have overlooked?

Comment: The error message in your question tells you how to fix the problem. Your question states that it works locally but "*When executed on a remote machine I get errors authenticating to the TFS service*". You need to authenticate properly, ie to use accounts that have the necessary permissions.

Comment: Thank you for the response Adrian.  That was the obvious first place that I looked, but to no avail.  I can reliably authenticate to the TFS service from my local dev environment using the same credentials, but not from the test environment.  I exhausted all ideas so I moved onto the next option of handling the snapshot restoration in the workflow rather than in code.  Not sure which path I should continue down at this point

Answer (score 0):

To do what you propose you should switch to Release Management and create a separate test run for each of your groupings, in your case each test. You can use RM to orchestrate looping through each of your runs and executing then.

http://nakedalm.com/execute-tests-release-management-visual-studio-2013/

However running a UI test should not break your application and I would suggest that either your tests are way too long, or there is some flaw in the design of your application.

Comment: Thank you MrHinsh.  I wasn't aware that Release Management was a thing.  I will have to look into that.  This automation is specifically to test an installer that also installs a third party component which is known for making undocumented changes to an environment.  I cannot reliably cleanup after the installer after each test, so it's easier to just revert to a clean shapshot before performing the next test.